# Are Android NDK file operations faster

Tags: android, c, performance, android-ndk

I have an Android application which does a lot of file operations (open, read, close).
Doing this takes a while, so I want to know if I implement these operations using C, can I improve the performance of my application?

If the answer is simply yes, is there any research to this topic?

Comment: When you used Traceview to determine precisely where you are spending your time, what did you learn?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do I/O with the standard Java libraries.  Depending on what you're doing, some approaches will be faster than others.  Switching to native code is not always a performance win.